# Matrix Multiplication in cvxpy

Tags: matrix, constraints, matrix-multiplication, cvxpy

I want to include a constraint in cvxpy where 2 consecutive matrix multiplications need to be done. However it keeps saying I have a DCP error. There seems to be something wrong with the way I am doing two matrix multiplication in the constraint function.

```
import cvxpy as cp

# yield is an 5x1 np array
# cov is an 5x5 np array
 
weight =  cp.Variable(5)
objective = cp.Maximize(weight @ yield)
constraint = [cp.sqrt(weight.T @ cov @ weight) < 10]
```

Comment: You have to use ``cp.quad_form``.

Comment: A couple of things I want to point out. -You seem have used strict inequality in the constraint part, which is not allowed. You can check this [link](https://www.cvxpy.org/version/1.2/api_reference/cvxpy.constraints.html#:~:text=Strict%20inequalities%20are%20not%20supported%2C%20as%20they%20do%20not%20make%20sense%20in%20a%20numerical%20setting.) 2nd, I am unable to recreate the problem since lack of the data set, would be great if you could share those but with some arbitrary values, it seems to work fine(after changing the inequality `constraint = [cp.sqrt(weight.T @ cov @ weight) <= 10`

Answer (score 0):

## cvxpy

You should use `cp.quad_from`

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Example random data for 'yield' (expected returns) and 'cov' (covariance matrix)
# np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
# yield_data = np.random.rand(5)
# cov_data = np.random.rand(5, 5)

yield_data=np.array([1,1,2,3,5]).T
cov_data=np.array([[2,3,4,5,6], [1,-1,1,-1,1], [2,3,5,10,18], [3,5,10,18,31], [5,10,18,31,59]])
cov_data = cov_data @ (cov_data.T)  # To ensure the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite

weight = cp.Variable(5)
objective = cp.Maximize(weight @ yield_data)  # Maximize expected return

# The risk constraint using cp.quad_form
risk_constraint = [cp.quad_form(weight, cov_data) <= 100.0]

# Create problem
problem = cp.Problem(objective, risk_constraint)

# Solve the problem
my_solver=cp.SCS # For example, 'ECOS', 'SCS', or 'OSQP'.
problem.solve(qcp=True, solver=my_solver, verbose=True)

# Output the results
print("Optimal weights:", weight.value)
print("Maximum yield:", problem.value)
```

```
Optimal weights: [ 0.71954993  3.73671039 10.76850287 -0.87183563 -2.94863196]
Maximum yield: 8.634599358453992
```

## MATLAB, with CVX

```matlab
clear all;close all;clc;
% Define the 'yield' data and covariance matrix
yield_data = [1; 1; 2; 3; 5];
cov_data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6; 1, -1, 1, -1, 1; 2, 3, 5, 10, 18; 3, 5, 10, 18, 31; 5, 10, 18, 31, 59];
cov_data = cov_data * (cov_data.');  % Ensure the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite

% Start CVX modeling
cvx_begin
    variable weight(5)
    % Objective function: Maximize expected return
    maximize( (weight.') * yield_data)
    
    % Risk constraint using quad_form equivalent in CVX
    subject to
        quad_form(weight, cov_data) <= 100
cvx_end

% Display the results
disp('Optimal weights:');
disp(weight);
disp('Maximum yield:');
disp(cvx_optval);
```

```
Status: Solved
Optimal value (cvx_optval): +8.63459
 
Optimal weights:
    0.7196
    3.7367
   10.7685
   -0.8718
   -2.9486

Maximum yield:
    8.6346
```

## gurobipy

```py
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import numpy as np

# Initialize the model
model = gp.Model("Optimization")

# Define the yield data and covariance matrix
yieldData = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
matrixTmp = np.array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, -1, 1, -1, 1], [2, 3, 5, 10, 18], [3, 5, 10, 18, 31], [5, 10, 18, 31, 59]])
covData = list(matrixTmp @ (matrixTmp.T))

# Variables
vars = model.addVars(5, lb=-GRB.INFINITY, name="x")

# Objective function to maximize
model.setObjective(gp.quicksum(yieldData[i] * vars[i] for i in range(5)), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Risk constraint
model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(covData[i][j] * vars[i] * vars[j] for i in range(5) for j in range(5)) <= 100, "riskConstraint")

# Solve the optimization problem
model.optimize()

# Output the results
if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    solution = model.getAttr('x', vars)
    print('Optimal solution:', solution)
else:
    print('Optimal solution not found')
```

```
Barrier solved model in 5 iterations and 0.02 seconds (0.00 work units)
Optimal objective 8.63459397e+00

Optimal solution: {0: 0.7195480456498428, 1: 3.7367177188654557, 2: 10.768462899578644, 3: -0.8718144333141845, 4: -2.9486308590678565}
```

## MATLAB, with YALMIP

```matlab
% Clear workspace and command window
clear all;close all;clc;

% Define the yield data and covariance matrix
yieldData = [1; 1; 2; 3; 5];
matrixTmp = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6; 1, -1, 1, -1, 1; 2, 3, 5, 10, 18; 3, 5, 10, 18, 31; 5, 10, 18, 31, 59];
covData = matrixTmp * (matrixTmp.');

% Variables
x = sdpvar(5, 1);

% Objective function to maximize
objective = (yieldData.') * x;

% Risk constraint
riskConstraint = sum(sum((x * (x.') ) .* covData)) <= 100;

% Options
options = sdpsettings('solver', 'gurobi');

% Solve the optimization problem
sol = optimize(riskConstraint, -objective, options); % Note: Negate objective for maximization

% Output the results
if sol.problem == 0
    % Solution found
    disp('Maximum value:');
    disp(value(objective));
    solution = value(x);
    disp('Optimal solution:');
    disp(solution);
else
    % Solution not found
    disp('Optimal solution not found');
end
```

```
Gurobi Optimizer version 11.0.0 build v11.0.0rc2 (win64 - Windows 10.0 (19045.2))

CPU model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2]
Thread count: 6 physical cores, 12 logical processors, using up to 12 threads

Optimize a model with 6 rows, 11 columns and 21 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x1e2050ed
Model has 1 quadratic constraint
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [4e-01, 7e+01]
  QMatrix range    [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 5e+00]
  Bounds range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+01, 1e+01]
Presolve removed 6 rows and 6 columns
Presolve time: 0.02s
Presolved: 1 rows, 6 columns, 1 nonzeros
Presolved model has 1 second-order cone constraint
Ordering time: 0.00s

Barrier statistics:
 AA' NZ     : 0.000e+00
 Factor NZ  : 1.000e+00
 Factor Ops : 1.000e+00 (less than 1 second per iteration)
 Threads    : 1

                  Objective                Residual
Iter       Primal          Dual         Primal    Dual     Compl     Time
   0   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00e+00 1.93e+00  3.23e+00     0s
   1  -3.50314413e+00 -2.66729383e+00  0.00e+00 6.44e-01  7.58e-01     0s
   2  -8.62620122e+00 -9.12755292e+00  0.00e+00 7.09e-07  7.16e-02     0s
   3  -8.63457394e+00 -8.63509903e+00  0.00e+00 1.91e-10  7.50e-05     0s
   4  -8.63459393e+00 -8.63459452e+00  0.00e+00 3.79e-11  8.50e-08     0s

Barrier solved model in 4 iterations and 0.04 seconds (0.00 work units)
Optimal objective -8.63459393e+00

Warning: to get QCP duals, please set parameter QCPDual to 1
Maximum value:
    8.6346

Optimal solution:
    0.7195
    3.7367
   10.7685
   -0.8718
   -2.9486
```

## Mathematica

```js
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Define the yield data and covariance matrix*)
yieldData = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5};
matrixTmp = {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, -1, 1, -1, 1}, {2, 3, 5, 10, 
    18}, {3, 5, 10, 18, 31}, {5, 10, 18, 31, 59}};
covData = matrixTmp . Transpose[matrixTmp];

(*Variables*)
vars = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 5];

(*Objective function to maximize*)
objective = vars . yieldData;

(*Risk constraint*)
riskConstraint = Sqrt[vars . covData . vars] <= 10;

(*Solve the optimization problem*)
solution = NMaximize[{objective, riskConstraint}, vars]

(*Output the results*)
solution
```

```
{8.63459, {Subscript[x, 1] -> 0.719549, Subscript[x, 2] -> 3.73671, 
  Subscript[x, 3] -> 10.7685, Subscript[x, 4] -> -0.871835, 
  Subscript[x, 5] -> -2.94863}}
```